# Sending audio signal from mixer to laptop wirelessly

Tags: wireless, transmitter

I'm trying to set up audio responsive mapping on music parties. Up until now I used a condenser mic to grab a signal from loudspeakers, but due to high volumes and a domination of low frequencies I want to switch to a cleaner audio source.

Ideally I'd like to connect a device directly to the mixer and send the signal through wireless channel to the laptop located up to 80 meters away.

I did some research on hardware reciever/transmitter pairs working both on BT and Wi-Fi, but still I welcome any feedback and ideas on this matter.

Cheers,
YU

Answer (score 1):

A Google search with "audio wireless transmitter" will find many solutions.

However, Bluetooth comes with a latency which may not be suitable with your need. Many solutions are analog.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.it.html).

You need:

- for sending: a computer "A" with sound card and VLC installed
- a router
- for receiving: a computer/smartphone "B" with VLC installed

Connect some outs of the mixer to the laptop "A" (use the sound card). Open VLC on this laptop and route the audio stream to the computer "B".

"A" and "B" must be connected to the same router.

In depth, VLC's IP settings are necessary.

You can start learning from this video.